# What could be steps that we should generally follow to resolve VF reRender issue?

Tags: visualforce, rerender, rendered

I have came across this many times and have spent many hours to resolve VF render issue, suppose I have page with `id="page"` , form with `id="mainform"`, and a panel with `id="mainpanel"`, so when I wanted to rerender `mainpanel` it worked with just `rerender="mainpanel"`, some times it worked when I put `rerender="page:mainform:mainpanel"`. Most of the times I couldn't figure out what was root cause for rerender issue. Need help on steps that We can follow whenever we came across rerender issue.

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having with rerender?

Comment: @DavidCheng I am asking for general guidelines when troubleshooting render issues, Rerending is kind of confusing some times. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: imo, this question is too broad and/or primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

The panel you want to rerender, in rerender put id of that panel or id of immediate parent panel/form.
And in rerender attribute seperate ids by comma not colon so that it can 
rerender parent block as well.  And if parent is rerendered, child will be rerendered automatically.